# Is str[0] of type char or of type string?

Tags: c#

I have a string: 
`string str = "abc"`.

What is `str[0]` type? `Char` or `String`?

Comment: It's a type of `char`

Comment: simple answer, its of type `char`, Your question will be closed soon

Comment: Strings are char arrays. It should be char since it holds only one character.

Comment: Why not write a simple 1-3 line program to find out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a Char since you are taking the first character of the string

I made a very simple console application that finds this out for you:

```
        string test = "test";

        var stringIndex = test[0];

        var stringOrChar = stringIndex.GetType();

        Console.WriteLine(stringOrChar);
        Console.ReadKey();
```

The output is "System.Char"

Comment: thanks for the help, i am new to "stackoverflow" can you tell me how can i give you points for the answer and i will do it.

Comment: You mark the answer as the answer to the left of it

Answer (score 0):

The answer is **if str is a string then str[0] of type char**. This is because  A [string/Text](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms228362.aspx) in .Net is stored as a sequential read-only collection of Char objects, and are follows Zero based indexing. So your `str[0]` will be the Character at 0th index.

```
char strChar=str[0]; // it is a valid assignment
```

Additional note : You will get the char array from the String by using `.ToCharArray()` method

```
 char[] charArrayOfString = str.ToCharArray();
```

Comment: @ down voter care to comment the reason please

Comment: The answer doesn´t help since you are casting the type to char, which was pretty much what the question giver wanted explained

Comment: You should use your voting privileges, answering bad questions just encourages more bad questions.

Comment: Much better explanation, so I voted up, nice change

Comment: I don´t understand why the question is bad though, I wish there had been questions like this with good answers when I was a true junior

Comment: @MikaelPuusaari - Because the op is just asking us to do their work for them, a work order - [Is showing effort needed?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288176/1324033)

Comment: Oh ok, got it, I am quite new to answering and voting on the site, but trying to learn, thanks for the explanation.. explanations are rare :)